# Delphi XE2 access violation in Win 7 64 bits but not in Win 8

Tags: delphi, access-violation

I have a Delphi XE2 application (32 bit) that runs in a Windows 8 machine but gives a access violation error in a Windows 7 64-bits with 6GB RAM.

I would understand if I was accessing a large amount of data but it simply states something as:

```
    Access violation at address 0000CD31. Read of address 00000000.
```

The address is always consistent. So is the read of address.

Usually from what Ive read this is a pointer trying to access a portion of memory that is no longer valid/in use. But my doubt arises why it works on Windows 8 and not on Windows 7 64 bits...

I have not been able to reproduce this in a local VM (Same Windows in same language in case it was a language issue) and this only happens on the client's PC.

Another even almost worst issue is that I am debugging this for a work colleague so I do not have access to the code and can't try another function (a fix I've read around here) to see if its that or not. So I cant use something like madExpert to actually debug the code. I would need something remote that can tell me information about the program fully complied and running remotely when the access violation happens.

Comment: There's a bug in the code. If you aren't able or prepared to do any debugging you'll find it hard to solve the problem. Since you've ruled out all the viable options this isn't really a useful question for anyone else, or even for you. Good luck.

Comment: I don't have direct access to the code and the programmer that works on this section is right now on absenteeism due to a injury. I suggested madExpert as you can see because I think that would be the best way to solve this but If I do not have access to the code, there is no way to do it.

Comment: There's not a lot of point in you continuing since even if you could identify the problem you can't fix it because you aren't able to build a new executable

Comment: You are accessing a nil pointer somewhere...

Comment: A explanation to the client is all that is needed. Once a explanation is given then he can work on the code once the programmer is back.

Comment: Why was this downvoted exactly?

Answer (score 1):

If you can't build in something like madexcept, your options are impov limited to

- WER
- procdump
- Reverse engineer the addres to the source code

From those, the easiest is [procdump](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx)

```
procdump -ma -w yourprocess
```

After you get a dump, you can analyze it with `windbg`

```
!analyze  -v
```

That should show you a stack trace that leads to the problem.

Comment: Trying to get the standalone windbg but man, it is difficult to get alone. You have to install the entire SDK...

Comment: That's not necesary. If you can spend the time, take a look at defrag tools on channel 9 on how to build your own usb thumb drive ready for debugging *([Andrew Richards series](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-Building-your-USB-thumbdrive))*

Comment: Ah but then you have ample time ;)

Comment: Couldn't install the SDK and the programmer on this code doesn't want to use madExpert. Guess this one will remain unsolved. We are testing it out if it happens in a VM as well.

Comment: @riahc3 - it's been a while since I configured my own thumbdrive but afaik, installing the entire SDK is not required?! You just need to extract the debuggers from it. Did you view the defrag tools session on getting the debugger? If an install is needed (can't remember), can't you try another computer?